# how can i set Path of ffmpeg output in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, ffmpeg

I am Writing a code in vb.net to Create thumbnails of  Video . But I want to set  the output path or the storage path of the thumbnails

```
enter code here

  TextBox2.Text = InputBox("Enter your Desired Name")
  Dim fileName As String = TextBox1.Text
  Dim result As String = Path.GetFileName(fileName)
  proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "  -i  " + result + " -r  1 " + TextBox2.Text + "%4d.jpg  "
  proc.Start()
```

When i run this The output is stored elsewhere. So i want to store the output manually

Comment: You already set the filename, so give it the full path where to store it?

Comment: I  cant find that   what is argument to for set   the path ?

Comment: You tell it to write into a file, give it s full path and not just a filename. It's not a separate parameter

Comment: it  is not working as i write ? Can u give a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the full path for the file>

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "  -i  " + result + " -r  1 D:\\folder\\" + TextBox2.Text + "%4d.jpg  "
```

Comment: it is working but.. i think some problem in path setting...thanks